# JavaScript code block messing with drop-downs in Menu

Tags: javascript, navigation, content-editor-web-part

I am using SharePoint 2010 and I need to place the following JavaScript code on a page to give me time in Rome

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

  function GetTime() {
  var dt = new Date();
  var def = dt.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
  var gmt = (dt.getHours() + def);

  var ending = ":" + IfZero(dt.getMinutes());
  var rome =check24(((gmt + 5) > 24) ? ((gmt + 5) - 24) : (gmt + 5));

  document.getElementById("LocalTime2").innerHTML = (IfZero(rome) + ending);
  setTimeout("GetTime()", 1000);
  }
  function IfZero(num) {
    return ((num <= 9) ? ("0" + num) : num);
  }
  function check24(hour) {
    return (hour >= 24) ? hour - 24 : hour;
  }
  //  End -->
  window.onload = GetTime;

 </script>

 <span id="LocalTime2"></span>
```

Currently I placed it in a CEWP and it does work, but then when I click save my drop down navigations from the menu stop working and I cant edit the page again.

Getting the following error message:

> Message:
>   'SP.Ribbon.PageState.ImportedNativeData.PageState'
>   is null or not an object Line: 2 Char:
>   79472 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://cpts1-spointdev/_layouts/sp.ribbon.js?rev=F%2BUEJ66rbXzSvpf7nN69wQ%3D%3D

Any idea why this is happening?

Any other work-around that I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your window.onload try this

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("GetTime");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Glad it worked! :)