# where can i write javascript in sharepoint

Tags: javascript

Please tell me where can I write javascript for a sharepoint site and what are the possible ways to write a javascript code for a sharepoint site.

Answer (score 3):

Approach 1 :

You can define your java script code in code behind file and than you can register it using Page.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered as shown below.

```
private const string strJQueryScript = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"+
                                         Your Script content here.
                                            "</script>";
```

Once you created your script you can later use following code in "OnPreRender" method.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{

if (!Page.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("jquerythickbox"))
                Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("jquerythickbox",
                  strJQueryScript);
}
```

Approach2:

You can place ContentEditorWebPart on the page and write Javascript code there.

Approach3:

Create your javascript file and put it in _Layouts folder. Once you have your javascript file you can modify your master page and register tag as shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/_layouts/YourFolderName/YourFile.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be even easier than the other answers: You can simply put the JavaScript into a Content Editor Web Part. It all depends on what your goals are, e.g., how widely you want to use the script, what it does, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add some JavaScript to the existing user interface without having to modify your existing pages or solution then check out our free [Muhimbi SharePoint Infuser](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/07/massage-sharepoint-into-submission.html) tool.

Comment: Could you please edit this answer to make it clear this is your company's product? It does answer the question directly so I guess isn't technically spam, but clear attribution would help. Thanks!

Comment: No worries Alex, I have reworded it. It is a free tool so didn't bother with the attribution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a question that I asked on the matter [Click Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9370/javascript-code-block-messing-with-drop-downs-in-menu)

As you will see I also made use of a CEWP.......